# source .bashrc from .cshrc

Tags: bash, csh

Is it possible to source a **.bshrc** file from **.cshrc** in a **non-interactive** session?
I'm asking because tcsh is our default shell at work and the .cshrc has to be used to set up the environment initially.
However, I am not really familiar with the tcsh and I have my own set-up in bash, so right now I have the following lines at the end of my .cshrc file:

```
if ( $?prompt && -x /bin/bash) then
  exec /bin/bash
endif
```

This works fine, loading my environment from .bashrc and giving me a bash prompt for interactive sessions but now I also need the same set-up for non-interactive sessions, e.g. to run a command remotely via SSH with all the correct PATHs etc.
I can't use 'exec' in that case but I can't figure out how to switch to bash and load the bash config files "non-interactively".
All our machines share the same home directory, so any changes to my local *rc files will affect the remote machiens as well.

Any ideas welcome - thank you for your help!

Comment: Much the best trick is to abandon `csh` and use `bash` all the time.

Comment: If `bash` is installed, used `chsh` to change your login shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I'm now quite sure that this won't work, but of course feel free to prove me wrong!

To load the environment in bash I have to switch to a bash shell. Even if that is possible "in the background", i.e. without getting a prompt, it would still break any tcsh commands which would then be attempted to execute under bash.

Hmmmm, back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

If `$command` is set there are arguments to `csh`, so it is a remote shell command. This works for me in `.cshrc`:

```
if ($?command) then
  echo Executing non-interactive command in bash: $command $*
  exec /bin/bash -c "${command} $*"
endif
echo Interactive bash shell
exec bash -l
```

Test:

```
$ ssh remotehost set | grep BASH
BASH=/bin/bash
...
```

proves that it ran in Bash.